# expo-av and react-native-track-player use incompatibile versione of exoplayer

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-track-player

I use expo for my app, all work fine in sdk 44 except a few bugs, to resolve that bugs I need to upgrade to sdk 45, now the problem is that in sdk 45 expo-av use an exoplayer versione incompatible with react-native-track-player.

Is it possible to downgrade expo-av to the version used in sdk 44? I've tried to do that by disinstalling and reainstallinge expo-av 10.2.1 with yarn, but the eas build fails with the following error: Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.1.

Anyone may help me to solve this compatibilitt issue?